# Can we use sagemaker model python CLI without using s3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to train the Anthropic model to understand the table of data and it's meta data(table about how the tables are related). Then use it to generate an SQL to fetch the data from database. I want to train the Anthropic model with the Excel data because I don't have access for S3 bucket. I want the data to be directly accessed from the local drive. Here is what I'm trying to to but without S3 bucket.

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-genai-datamesh/blob/main/blogs/Simple-text-to-sql/mda_with_llm_langchain_byo_model_without_cloudformation.ipynb

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-genai-datamesh/tree/main

Please let me know if there is any way to use the model without S3 bucket. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use EFS with Sagemaker

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/mount-an-efs-file-system-to-an-amazon-sagemaker-notebook-with-lifecycle-configurations/